# kubelet: W0403 conversion.go:110 Could not get instant cpu stats: different number of cpus

Tags: kubernetes

In my kubernetes host syslog, I see these message frequently. how to fix this warning message?

```
 kubelet: W0403 12:48:50.866950    1460 conversion.go:110] Could not get instant cpu stats: different number of cpus
```

thanks
SR

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using ?

Comment: I am running V1.9.0

Comment: That error belongs to cadvisor, the services of k8s starts sometimes kube-apiserver starts sligtly slower than kubelet. Than kubelet try to get cpu metrics from cadvisor (running within the kube-apiserver).

For that reason you can see the error only once.

Stop all the servicies and start them manually one by one and probably you wont see that error.